# Why AlarmManager doesn't exactly repeating on device?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

Why **AlarmManager** sometimes fails to execute exactly 5 minutes later, as it is supposed to? For example, at one time it may not work, but in the next period it works 2 (or 3) times. Or even lags for 1 minute.

**API 17** (Android 4.2.1) - **setRepeating** should be exact.

```
public void scheduleAlarm()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestAlarmReceiver.class);
        final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, TestAlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis, 5 * 60 * 1000, pIntent); // every 5 minutes

        Log.i(TAG_LOG, "The alarm started");
    }
```

Logs:

```
<...>
17.03.2017 07:20:30
17.03.2017 07:25:30
17.03.2017 07:30:30
17.03.2017 07:40:25  <- this
17.03.2017 07:40:30  <- this
17.03.2017 07:45:30
17.03.2017 07:50:30
17.03.2017 07:55:30
17.03.2017 08:00:30
17.03.2017 08:10:25  <- this
17.03.2017 08:10:30  <- this
17.03.2017 08:15:30
17.03.2017 08:20:30
<...>
17.03.2017 16:50:30
17.03.2017 16:55:30
17.03.2017 17:01:10  <- this
17.03.2017 17:05:30
17.03.2017 17:10:30
17.03.2017 17:15:30
17.03.2017 17:21:08  <- this
17.03.2017 17:25:30
17.03.2017 17:40:29  <- this
17.03.2017 17:40:29  <- this
17.03.2017 17:40:30  <- this
17.03.2017 17:45:30
17.03.2017 17:51:09  <- this
17.03.2017 17:55:30
17.03.2017 18:00:50
<...>
```

Answer (score 0):

`setRepeating()` is not supposed to work the way you want.

`setExact()` triggers the alarm at the exact time but since there is no `setExactRepeating()` method, you need to use `setExact()`, and in the `BroadcastReceiver`, call the `setExact()` function again.

There is no simple method to do this because Google is trying to point out to you that this is bad for the battery. Using `setExact()` as described above is your only option for exact repeating.

Comment: Yep, but I mentioned that I have **API 17**. There is no `setExact()` on it.